Why does block coding via typical strings give messages longer than $nH(p)$?
This semester, I am taking a course on quantum information and quantum computing. Since I am rather new to information theory I have a problem with understanding a paragraph in my lecture notes. The paragraph goes as follows
"In general, to convey essentially all the information carried by a string of n bits, it suffices to choose a block code that assigns a nonnegative integer to each of the typical strings. This block code needs to distinguish about $2^{nH(p)}$ messages (all occurring with nearly equal a priori probability), so we may specify any one of the messages using a binary string with length only slightly longer than $nH(p)$."
$H(p)$ is the shannon entropy. I will now just give my interpretation of this paragraph but I do not know if I'm correct: So we have strings of n bits (if n = 3 this can be 010 for example) and we want to create some code in order to shorten these strings of n bits. Since we take n to be big we only consider the typical messages which occur commonly and these are a total of $2^{nH(p)}$ messages (i get how we come to this number). We do this by giving each typical string of n bits a nonnegative number (so I think for example if n=3 we assign to the string 010 the number 2 for example?). The next step I think is that we can express all these nonnegative numbers with binary code so the 2 becomes 10? Now i do not understand what they then mean by saying every message will be slightly longer than $nH(p)$. I do get that if this is the case all messages will become shorter, but I just do not see why all messages using this "block code" will become slightly longer than $nH(p)$. Also in general what is a block code? If anyone could help me understand this problem I would grealty appreciate it :))
P.S: Sorry if it is explained a bit vaguely

check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

The question suggests that you're missing some key concepts. It might make sense to read a standard text to catch up. For instance, assuming you're familiar with standard information theoretic functionals, Chapters 3 and 5 of Cover and Thomas should get you up to speed.

Imagine you have a set of $64 = 2^6$ equiprobable symbols that you want to encode with a binary code. A posible (valid, trivial) code is to assign the $6-$bit lengths binary representations of the numbers $0,1, 2 \cdots 63$. (Incidentally: this is not the optimal code in general, but it is when the symbols are equiprobable... as intuition says).
So, if we have $A=2^n$ symbols, there exists a binary code of length $n = \log_2 A$. If $n$ is not an integer, then at least we can round it up to the next integer. Then, in general, we can always code $A$ symbols with $ \log_2 A \le \ell  < \log_2 A +1$ bits, or in words (when $A$ is large) : "$\log_2 A$ bits or slightly more", or "nearly $\log_2 A$ bits".
Then, if the typical set has $A=2^{n H}$ symbols, we can encode the typical set with nearly $\log_2 A = nH$ bits ( or slightly more).
Incidentally, because the elements of that set are almost equiprobable, our trivial code will be almost optimal.

maybe i'm misunderstanding you, but if the typical set has $2^{nH}$ symbols, then by definition don't you need exactly (not slightly more than) $nH$ bits?

Only if $nH$ is an integer - which is not the case, in general.

The context here is that you want to compress information. More specifically, you have a string of $n$ bits, each one of which you're assuming is drawn from a binary probability distribution $(1-p,p)$ (meaning $p$ is the probability of each bit being $1$). You're looking for some map, call it $\operatorname{Enc}$, which compresses information down in a way that is retrievable with the least amount of error.
$n=2$ samples example
Suppose for example you're drawing $n=2$ samples and $p=1/3$. The probability distribution over the possible outcome strings is:
$$P(00)=(1-p)^2 = 4/9,
\qquad P(01)= P(10)= p(1-p)=2/9,
\qquad P(11)=p^2=1/9.$$
Note in particular that $01$ and $10$ are equiprobable.
The entropy of this distribution is $H(p)=\log3 -\frac23\log 2\simeq 0.92$.
If you were to instead use the (provably optimal) Huffman coding strategy, you'd get the map $00\to1$, $10\to 01$, $01\to 001$, $11\to000$ (note that Huffman is an errorless variable-length coding strategy), and thus average coding length $\ell=17/9=1.\bar 8$, i.e. $\ell> 2 H(p)\simeq 1.84$, as expected.
Another possibly naive encoding strategy is to only consider the equiprobable strings $(01)$ and $(10)$ in your compression strategy. In other words, use the block encoding $\operatorname{Enc}:\mathbb{Z}_2^2\to \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $\operatorname{Enc}(01)= (0)$, $\operatorname{Enc}(10)=(1)$, while the other strings (here $00$ and $11$) are just sent to some null symbol.
The decoding function just inverts this relation, mapping $0\to 01$ and $1\to 10$.
Note that this strategy fails whenever the input is one of $00$ and $11$, and thus has a success probability of $2p(1-p)=4/9$. The length of the encoding is trivially $\ell=1$.
This strategy gives you a smaller encoding length, but that's because it has a much larger error rate.
Note that in this simple example $(01)$ and $(10)$ are the "most typical" strings, as you might expect. To see it, observe that the empirical average entropies for all strings are
$$h(01)= h(10)= \frac12\log\left(\frac31\frac32\right) \simeq 1.08,\\
h(11)=\frac12\log\left(\frac31\frac31\right) \simeq 1.58,
\qquad h(00)=\frac12 \log\left(\frac32\frac32\right)\simeq 0.39,
$$
to compare with the true entropy $H(p)\simeq 0.92$. More precisely put, taking $\epsilon=0.2$, the $\epsilon$-typical strings are $\{(01),(10)\}$.
These results might seem at odd with the given statement, but that's only because $n=2$ is very far from the asymptotic limit $n\to\infty$. The results you're mentioning are essentially Shannon's source coding theorem, which states that if you want asymptotically zero decoding error, you need an average coding length larger than $n H(p)$.
In practice, when using the typical coding strategy, the "larger than $n H(p)$ coding length" comes from the fact that you're using $\epsilon$-typical strings. The $\epsilon$ bit is crucial, because it means you're encoding function will use more than just $2^{nH(p)}$ strings.
Let's try to see this with more examples.
$n=3$ case
Let's again fix $p=1/3$ but take $n=3$. The probabilities are now
$$P(000) = 2^3/3^3\simeq 0.30,
\qquad P(001) = 2^2/3^3 \simeq 1.49,\\
P(011) = 2/3^3 \simeq 0.07,
\qquad P(111) = 1/3^3 = 0.04,
$$
where I wrote the probability of a single member of each typicality class for conciseness (meaning eg $010$ and $100$ have the same probability as $001$, etc).
The corresponding empirical entropies are
$$
h(000) = \frac13\log(27/8) \simeq 0.58,
\qquad
h(001) = \frac13\log(27/4) \simeq 0.92
\\
h(011) = \frac13\log(27/2) \simeq 1.25,
\qquad
h(111) = \frac13\log(27) \simeq 1.58.
$$
So fixing $\epsilon=0.1$, we see that as expected the $\epsilon$-typical strings are $(001),(010),(100)$.
If you use the block coding strategy of just ignoring every string that's not $\epsilon$-typical, the error probability is
$$p_{\rm err} = \frac{1}{27}(2^3 + 3\times 2 + 1) = 5/9.$$
The error probability is the same as before, but now we're using a smaller $\epsilon$, so that's not strange. Coding length is still exactly $nH(p)$, because with this choice of $\epsilon$ and $n$ the typical strings are those with exactly the shape $(011)$. So let's consider larger $n$ to capture more features.
Large $n$ case
We're keeping $\epsilon=0.1$ to stay in the spirit of the theorem, but let's start considering large values of $n$ to try and capture the asymptotic features.
The general strategy is unchanged: look for $\epsilon$-typical sequences, and compress the message by "filtering out" every sequence that's not $\epsilon$-typical. You're ensured there's always at most $2^{n(H+\epsilon)}$ of those, thus using $n(H+\epsilon)$ bits is enough to perform this compression. For large $n$, the probability of a sequence being $\epsilon$-typical approaches $1$, thus this compression scheme has error probability asymptotically vanishing.
We can try to visualise this as follows:

where the left figure shows the empirical entropy computed for all possible sequence types, with red dashed horizontal lines marking the threshold set by $\epsilon=0.1$ that determine whether the sequence type is $\epsilon$-typical or not. The horizontal axis is the number of $0$s in the sequence type.
The right plot is the probability associated with each sequence type (again, horizontal axis marks number of $0$s in the type). The red points correspond to those types that are $\epsilon$-typical, and thus the sum of the heights of the red point is the success probability of the compression scheme.
Finally, observe that the direct answer to the question is that in general you have more than $2^{nH}$ typical sequences, as the theorem only ensures you have at most $2^{n(H+\epsilon)}$.
Furthermore, as noted in the other answer, even if you did have exactly $2^{nH}$ typical sequences, if $H$ (and thus $nH$) isn't an integer, you'd still need slightly more than $nH$ bits to encode them. What cannot happen is that you get less than $2^{nH}$ typical sequences, because that would violate the known optimality of Huffman coding: it'd provide you with a compression scheme with vanishingly small error and average code length smaller than the optimal one, that is, $nH(X)$.
To still this explicitly in our case, consider the following data:

Horizontal axis corresponds to $n$, and vertical axis is in log scale. This plot clearly shows that the actual number of typical sequences is always between $2^{nH}$ and $2^{n(H+\epsilon)}$, as expected from the theory.
It's also worth noting that I'm not saying the number of typical sequences is always larger than $2^{nH}$. The bound you get from the theory (see eg the Wiki page) is
$$
(1-\epsilon) 2^{n(H(X)-\epsilon)} \le 
\lvert A_\epsilon^{(n)}\rvert\le 2^{n(H(X)+\epsilon)}.$$
And indeed, for smaller $n$ than shown in the above figure, you can absolutely have a number of typical sequences $\lvert A_\epsilon^{(n)}\rvert < 2^{nH(X)}$. However, this cannot be for large $n$, as at some point you're getting a near-optimal compression scheme, which therefore cannot have a compression length smaller than $nH(X)$.
Code for the figures
Here's the Mathematica code used to generate the figures:
With[{p = 1/3, eps = 0.1}, 
 With[{entropy = p Log[2, 1/p] + (1 - p) Log[2, 1/(1 - p)]},
  Manipulate[
   With[{typicalKs = 
      Select[Range@n, 
       Abs[1/n N@Log[2, 1/(p^(n - #) (1 - p)^#)] - entropy] <= eps &]},
    {DiscretePlot[
      1/n Log[2, 1/(p^(n - k) (1 - p)^k)],
      {k, 1, n}, PlotRange -> All, 
      Epilog -> {InfiniteLine[{0, 0.92}, {1, 0}], Red, Dashed, 
        InfiniteLine[{0, 0.92 + 0.1}, {1, 0}], 
        InfiniteLine[{0, 0.92 - 0.1}, {1, 0}]},
      GridLines -> Automatic,
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> 400
      ],
     ListPlot[
      Table[
       If[MemberQ[typicalKs, k], Style[#, Red], #] &@{k, 
         Binomial[n, k] p^(n - k) (1 - p)^k},
       {k, 1, n}],
      PlotRange -> All,
      GridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> False, Filling -> Bottom,
      Epilog -> {InfiniteLine[{0, 0.92}, {1, 0}], Red, Dashed, 
        InfiniteLine[{0, 0.92 + 0.1}, {1, 0}], 
        InfiniteLine[{0, 0.92 - 0.1}, {1, 0}]},
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> 400
      ]
     }
    ],
   {{n, 60}, 30, 300, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
   ]
  ]]


data = Table[
   With[{p = 1/3, eps = 0.1}, 
    With[{entropy = p Log[2, 1/p] + (1 - p) Log[2, 1/(1 - p)]},
     With[{typicalKs = 
        Select[Range@n, 
         Abs[1/n N@Log[2, 1/(p^(n - #) (1 - p)^#)] - entropy] <= 
           eps &]},
      {n,
       N@Sum[
         Binomial[n, k] ,
         {k, typicalKs}
         ],
       2^(n (entropy - eps)), 2^(n (entropy + eps)), 2^(n (entropy))
       }
      ]
     ]],
   {n, 30, 90}
   ];

With[{
  dataActual = {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ data,
  dataLower = {#[[1]], #[[3]]} & /@ data,
  dataUpper = {#[[1]], #[[4]]} & /@ data,
  dataMiddle = {#[[1]], #[[5]]} & /@ data
  },
 ListLogPlot[{dataActual, dataLower, dataUpper, dataMiddle}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledSmallCircle]", Small],
  PlotLegends -> {"number of typical sequences", 2^(
    n (H - \[Epsilon])), 2^(n (H + \[Epsilon])), 2^(n H)},
  GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True
  ]
 ]

